# xxd not doing anything on alpine linux

Tags: alpine-linux, busybox, xxd

I'm trying to use `xxd` to follow a tutorial but it's not printing anything from the Alpine Linux container that I'm trying to run it in.

I am running: `xxd -ps -c 1000 <valid-file-path>`. When I do this, it just prints out the usage instructions:

```
~ # xxd -ps -c 1000 $FILE_PATH
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.

Usage: xxd [OPTIONS] [FILE]

Hex dump FILE (or stdin)

    -g N        Bytes per group
    -c N        Bytes per line
    -p      Show only hex bytes, assumes -c30
    -l LENGTH   Show only first LENGTH bytes
    -s OFFSET   Skip OFFSET bytes
```

I seem to be calling it correctly according to the printed usage instructions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I discovered that the xxd available in alpine linux is not the same one that I see references to elsewhere online. I did `apk add xxd` and it installed what seems to be the common option, with many more flags. Using this newly installed version fixed the issue, though curious why alpine comes with something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpine comes with [busybox](https://busybox.net/about.html), which is a smaller version of the utilities that come with say, Ubuntu, [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). If you've heard people say "GNU/Linux", this is what they're referring to - many of the utilities you use on the command line were written by the Free Software Foundation.

Busybox `xxd` doesn't have the `-ps` option because it was rewritten to be smaller. It prints out the usage instructions because `-ps` is not valid. If you run this on macos or linux, you'll get different versions of the original `xxd`.

As you've found, `apk add xxd` will install this "original" xxd.