# xxd converts hex file to 32 bytes binary on Mac, 30 bytes on busy box?

Tags: bash, hex, xxd

I am using xxd to convert a file containing the following hex private key:

```
608e9b6f67c65e47531e08e8e501386dfae63a540fa3c48802c8aad854510b4e
```

simply by

```
xxd -r -p hex > bin
```

this command generates a binary with 32 bytes on Mac OS Big Sur `xxd V1.10 27oct98 by Juergen Weigert` and generates 30 bytes on busy box docker image `BusyBox v1.33.1 (2021-06-07 17:33:50 UTC)` I have no idea why ?

It should generate a 32 bytes binary on busy box.

Update #1 hex (hexdump of the binaries)

#### binary in busy box

```
00000000  60 8e 9b 6f 67 c6 5e 47  53 1e 08 e8 e5 01 38 6d  |`..og.^GS.....8m|
00000010  fa e6 3a 54 0f a3 c4 88  02 c8 aa d8 54 51        |..:T........TQ|
0000001e
```

#### binary in Mac OS Big Sur

```
00000000  60 8e 9b 6f 67 c6 5e 47  53 1e 08 e8 e5 01 38 6d  |`..og.^GS.....8m|
00000010  fa e6 3a 54 0f a3 c4 88  02 c8 aa d8 54 51 0b 4e  |..:T........TQ.N|
00000020
```

Comment: try `xxd -r -p -c 32 hex >bin`?

Comment: wild (useless?) thought ... wondering if there could be an issue with different implementation of `xxd`? while this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60943778) is related to an issue with command line args, it does point out that there are different implementations of `xxd` floating around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In xxd busybox implementation, argument `-c` defaults to a 30, changing it to 32, gives the same result as Mac OS Big Sur:

```
xxd -r -p -c 32 hex > bin
```